# MUI rating component broken. Cant find why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, components

I'm doing a project in react, I'm using bootstrap react Bootstrap and MUI for my components.

I need a rating so I use the MUI componet. I copied the basic code from the page but only 1 star has its css okay the other 4 doesnt have css and are above the first one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhZyi.png)

I see that the main span is correctly positioned next to the forst star but the label and inputs are aboove
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4k7W.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNAfF.png)

I tried styling the componet, using a div with the compoent, bbut nothing worked. The only thing that worked was setting the component in readmodeonly

Comment: A snippet of the code or a link to the code would help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.